# I kept on having an empty set result, is there a problem with my query statement?

Tags: mysql

I want to display the names of the students who are enrolled in the following courses IT, COMSCI, and MIS.

my code is:

```
Select fname,lname from student where course="IT" AND "COMSCI" AND "MIS";
```

I expect the result of my query to display all the names of students that are enrolled in the 3 course in one table, but the result is empty set, 7 warnings (0.00 sec).

Comment: Do you want students who are enrolled in any of those courses, or all of those courses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Select fname,lname from student where course="IT" OR course= "COMSCI" or course= "MIS";
```

also you can use

```
Select fname,lname from student where course in ("IT" ,"COMSCI" ,"MIS");
```